# jQuery in Template.rendered gets called but doesn't take effect

Tags: jquery, meteor

I am running into the following issue which I can't debug:

I have a list of textarea fields where I go

```
<template name="sampleTemplate">
<ul>
  {{#each listOfTextFields}}
   < li > < textarea id="{{_id}}" > </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
</template>
```

In order to render that list, I have

```
Template.sampleTemplate.listOfTextFields = function () {
   return applicationDB.find({ //some fields })
}
```

I also have an event mapped to the textareas where when I press the "enter" key, I insert a new document into the collection. When that happens, the template is re-rendered and the new textarea shows up.

```
Template.sampleTemplate.events({
   'keydown enter' : function (enterEv) {
        //add new document to collection
        Session.set("newTextAreaCreated", 1);
        Session.set("newItemId", newItemId);

    }
}
```

Then ... in order to make it more user friendly, I tried to focus() on that newly created document. So I have in my rendered function:

```
Template.sampleTemplate.rendered = function () {
    if (Session.get("newTextAreaCreated") == 1){
        console.log("new text area is created")
        $(document.getElementById(Session.get("newItemId")).focus();
    }
Session.set("newTextAreaCreated", 0);
}
```

The above code works when I am currently on the last textarea field and I when I press enter, it successfully creates the new item, and focuses on it. **I have got a whole heap of other code that handles the sorting so the newly item is definitely created underneath the new item** (just in case some of you may wonder).

BUT - when I go back up the list somewhere in the middle, I press enter, it successfully creates the item underneath it, however it doesn't focus on it. I have used console.logs to make sure the rendered function gets called and it does, but the focus is not apparent.

May be this has something to do with the 'enter' effect on text areas where it jumps a line? Or could be something completely different. I am more than happy to implement a better solution if textareas are causing problems etc.

Comment: In the Template.sampleTemplate.rendered function try adding a `console.log('rendered', Session.get("newTextAreaCreated"))` and see if it gets hit and what it outputs.  I wouldn't rely on the rendered function being called multiple times though, that is changing in the new version of the UI to only be called once.  You could always wrap a `Deps.autorun` around the `if` so if `newTextAreaCreated` changes it will be called again.

Comment: Try implementing the same feature but don't use the `enter` key. Why not use something more standard (and intuitive) like `add button`?

Comment: Also, what is that mysterious `newItemId` variable in your event callback?

Comment: I've managed to find the bug... the code is actually working except that because of a slight mistake in the mongodb query, it caused the focusing to focus on the wrong element.

Answer (score 0):

Put an {{#isolate}} block around your list items and delegate document insertions to server-side meteor methods. The isolate helper will ensure that the parent template doesn't re-render and the server-side meteor method will guarantee that simulations don't run on collection inserts. This way rendered() only gets triggered once and you can do DOM-related things like focusing or animation.

Comment: I partially implemented some of the things you mentioned. I moved one of the update statement to server-side and modified it so that it does a multi row update (which means it runs only once) and got rendered() to run only once as a result of that.